# Making the same change to every line in a BED/Interval file in python

Tags: python, inline-editing, genome

I have a BED Interval file that I'm trying to work with using the Galaxy online tool. Currently, every line in the file begins with a number (which stands for chromosome number). In order to upload it properly, I need every line to begin with "chr" and then the number. So for example lines that start with "2L", I need to change so that they will start with "chr2L", and do the same for every other line that start with a number (not just 2L, there are many different numbers). I was thinking if I could just add a "chr" to the start of every line, without affecting the other columns, that would be great, but I have no idea how to do that (very new to python)
Can you please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you constrained to use python (as opposed to something like sed, awk, or perl, which are designed for this kind of task)?

Comment: E.g. `perl -pi -e 's/^/chr/' inputfile.bde`

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines

```
with open('bed-interval') as f1, open('bed-interval-modified', 'w') as f2:
    f2.writelines('chr' + line for line in f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

step one open the file

```
  file = open("somefile.txt")
```

step 2 get the lines

```
  lines = list(file.readlines())
  file.close()
```

step 3 use a list comprehension

```
   new_lines = ["chr"+line for line in lines]
```

step 4 write new lines back to file

```
   with open("somefile.txt","w") as f:
       f.writelines(new_lines)
```

In order to not store all the lines in memory

```
   file1 = open("some.txt")
   file2 = open("output.txt","w")

   for line in file1:
       print >> file2, "chr"+ line

   file1.close()
   file2.close()
```

then just copy `output.txt` to your original filename

Comment: Does this require Python to hold all of the new or old lines in memory at once? I'm guessing that it does require that for the old lines.

Comment: or you could write to a different file and then at the end just copy over the original ...  but if you want to write to the same file you need to read in all the lines to memory

Comment: Ah, true. I missed the fact that you were writing back to the same file.